# Geth over HTTP RPC responding but doesn't return info to eth_blockNumber

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

I have a synced full node.

When I run:

```
# curl --location --request POST 'localhost:8545/' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{
        "jsonrpc":"2.0",
        "method":"eth_blockNumber",
        "params":[],
        "id":83
}'
```

This is the result:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":83,"result":"0x0"}
```

My start command:

```
docker run -d --name ethereum-node -v /root/ethereum:/root -p 127.0.0.1:8545:8545 -p 30303:30303            ethereum/client-go --http --http.addr "0.0.0.0"   --http.api="db,eth,net,web3,personal"
```

Why is it returning no data? I also tried getBalance from [Postman](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/4117254/ethereum-json-rpc/RVu7CT5J) but similarly received no data.

Edit: An eth_syncing call returns this:

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 1,
  "result": {
    "currentBlock": "0xd3408f",
    "healedBytecodeBytes": "0x558ce2",
    "healedBytecodes": "0x280",
    "healedTrienodeBytes": "0x7ee67350",
    "healedTrienodes": "0x7fe589",
    "healingBytecode": "0x0",
    "healingTrienodes": "0x9ea",
    "highestBlock": "0xd340fc",
    "startingBlock": "0xd33196",
    "syncedAccountBytes": "0x9126bc269",
    "syncedAccounts": "0x980eb2e",
    "syncedBytecodeBytes": "0xa98dcb1b",
    "syncedBytecodes": "0x73dc3",
    "syncedStorage": "0x223f6275",
    "syncedStorageBytes": "0x1cad724720"
  }
}
```